# Display results using foreach loop and sessions in Symfony for PHP

Tags: php, symfony, session, foreach, shopping-cart

I'm writing a shopping cart page for shoes shop website using sessions in Symfony for PHP. It enables to add an item of selected size to cart and count a quantity. I need to know how to display the cart using foreach loop.

Here's a function of adding a product:

```
public function add($shoesid, $sizeid, SessionInterface $session)
{
    $cart = $session->get('cart', []);
    if(!empty($cart[$shoesid][$sizeid])) {
        $cart[$shoesid][$sizeid]++;
    } else {
        $cart[$shoesid][$sizeid] = 1;
    }
    $session->set('cart', $cart);
    dd($session->get('cart'));
}
```

Here's a message what I get when I add an item:

```
> array:2 [▼   
40024 => array:1 [▼   
410 => 2     
]   
]
```

(where 40024 is shoesid, 410 is sizeid and 2 is quantity (count of [shoesid][sizeid])

And here's a function to display a shopping cart

```
public function index(SessionInterface $session, ShoesRepository $shoesRepository, CountriesRepository $countriesRepository, StockRepository $stockRepository)
{
    $cart = $session->get('cart', []);
    $cartWithData = [];
    foreach($cart as $shoesid => [$sizeid => $quantity]) //error here
    {
        $cartWithData[] = [
            'shoe' => $shoesRepository->shoeDescr($shoesid),
            'shoePrice' => $shoesRepository->find($shoesid),
            'quantity' => $quantity,
            'size' => $stockRepository->shoeSizeCart($shoesid, $sizeid)
        ];
    }        
    $total=0;
    $delivery=20;

    foreach($cartWithData as $item) 
    {
        $totalItem = $item['shoePrice']->getShoesPrice()*$item['quantity'];
        $total += $totalItem;            
    }
    $countries = $countriesRepository->findBy(array(), array('countryname' => 'asc'));
    dd($cartWithData);
}
```

But when I try to launch a cart page I get the next error (in line 9):

> Notice: Undefined variable: sizeid

What code changes should I make to display items correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$cart` appears to be a multi-dimensional array (two to be exact), with the following structure:

```
$cart = [
    <$shoeId> => [
        <$sizeId> => <count>,
        <$sizeId> => <count>,
        ...,
    ],
    <$shoeId> => [
        ...
    ],
];
```

You should have a `foreach()` loop for each level to iterate over. In this case, you should have two:

```
// Iterate on the 1st lelvel: shoes
foreach ($cart as $shoeId => $sizes) {
    // Iterate on the 2nd level: sizes
    foreach ($sizes as $sizeId => $quantity) {
        $cartWithData[] = [
            'shoe' => $shoesRepository->shoeDescr($shoeId),
            'shoePrice' => $shoesRepository->find($shoeId),
            'quantity' => $quantity,
            'size' => $stockRepository->shoeSizeCart($shoeId, $sizeId),
        ];
    }
}
```